# On Skinner and Urban's $p$-adic L functions

Tags: nt.number-theory

We know that if $\pi$ is an automorphic representation of $GL_2$ over a number field, the most important point for its $L$-function $L(s,\pi)$ is $s=\frac{1}{2}$. More specifically, in Skiner and Urbans situation in "The Iwasawa main conjecture for $GL_2$", the supposed interpolation property should link the $p$-adic $L$-function and $L_K(\pi,\chi,\frac{1}{2})$, i.e. $L_K(f,\chi,\frac{k}{2})$. Instead, their interpolation involves $L_K(f,\chi,k-1)$. My question is what the reason is.